Method of Steepest Descent to Evaluate the Gamma Integral
I am trying to evaluate that integral through the steepest descent method:
$$\Gamma(a,z)=\int_{z}^\infty e^{-t}e^{(a-1)\log t-t} dt,$$
I need to determine the leading asymptotic behavior of the function $f(z) = \Gamma(z + 1, z)$ when $|\arg z| < \pi$.
My attempt here is to expand the exponential argument in the integrand, $\exp(a g(t))$ where $g(t)=\log t+\frac{\log t}{a}-\frac{t}{a}$.
Then I Taylor expand the series and find the saddle point as:
$g'(t)=\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{at}-\frac{1}{a}=0$.
The saddle point is: $t_o=\frac{1}{a-1}$.
I can identify the Taylor's series terms around the saddle point, but I need to find phase angle $\phi$ as well by doing $a=e^{i\theta}$. But I am a bit puzzled regarding how to proceed the problem by making appropriate angles.
Any leads would be helful.

The "${}-t$" in the second exponential seems odd.  Is there a typo?

@Jpmg Did I answer your question?

Apologies for the late reply. Yes, I can proceed now with this.
Thank you.

@EricTowers no there isn't it is actually a question from graduate mathematical physics by Kelly.

By definition,
$$
\Gamma (z + 1,z) = \int_z^\infty  {t^z {\rm e}^{ - t} {\rm d}t} .
$$
Assume that $z>0$ and perform the change of variables via $t = z{\rm e}^s$, leading to
$$
\Gamma (z + 1,z) = z^{z + 1} \int_0^{+\infty}  {{\rm e}^{zs} {\rm e}^{ - z{\rm e}^s } {\rm e}^s {\rm d}s}  = z^{z + 1} {\rm e}^{ - z} \int_0^{+\infty}  {{\rm e}^{ - z({\rm e}^s  - s - 1)} {\rm e}^s {\rm d}s} .
$$
Let us now denote by $\mathscr{P}(\theta)$, with $\theta = \arg z$, the path of steepest descent starting from the origin (a saddle point), which coincides with the positive real axis when $\theta = 0$. Along this path, $\arg({\rm e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}({\rm e}^s - s - 1)) = 0$. Then, by analytic continuation, we have
$$
\Gamma (z + 1,z) = z^{z + 1} {\rm e}^{ - z} \int_{\mathscr{P}(\theta )} {{\rm e}^{ - z({\rm e}^s  - s - 1)} {\rm e}^s {\rm d}s} ,
$$
as long as $\mathscr{P}(\theta)$ deforms smoothly as $\theta$ varies from $0$. It can be verified that this is the case as long as $|\theta| < \frac{3\pi}{2}$. Thus, by the method of steepest descents, we obtain the asymptotic approximation
$$
\Gamma (z + 1,z) \sim  z^{z + 1/2} {\rm e}^{ - z} \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{2}} 
$$
as $z\to\infty$ in the sector $|\arg z|\le 2\pi-\delta$ ($<2\pi$).
